# I cannot find the ambiguity in the program but the compiler say ambiguity between check(int) and check(float)

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void check(int);
void check(float b);
void main()
{
     clrscr();
     check(10);
     check(2.5);
     getch();
}
void check(int c)
{
     cout<<c;
}
void check(float b)
{
     cout<<b;
}
```

I have defined two functions named check one take integer as argument and another take float as the argument. When i compile the program compiler find the ambiguity between the two function. I am unable to visualize the case. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try it with `check(2.5f)` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2.5` has type `double`, and C++ doesn't say that one narrowing conversion (to `int` or to `float`) is preferred over the other. Hence the call is ambiguous.

You can fix it either by calling `check(2.5f)` or (perhaps more usefully) by implementing `void check(double);` instead of or as well as the `float` overload.

Answer (score 0):

`2.5` is a `double`, not a `float`. There is no overload that exactly matches, and two that match after argument conversion, hence the ambiguity.

Change `2.5` to `2.5f` to specify a `float` literal.

Answer (score 0):

it's because `2.5` is a **double** literal.  you compiler doesn't know whether to convert it into a float or an int.

You can make it a **float** literal by putting the letter `f` at the end

```
check(2.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ by default the 2.5 will be treated as the double literal by the compiler so you have to   make type conversion of your literal before calling the function, please do that by 2.5f.